# What is the frontend Layout structure of Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, frontend, design

I wish to know which grid structure does magento 2 follow as in how many columns is the structure of and what is the gutter width in it.

Does anyone have documentation for magento 2 frontend designer as in what points should they keep in mind while designing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> The structure of sample page layout is as described

```
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="1column">
        <label translate="true">1 column</label>
    </layout>
    <layout id="2columns-left">
        <label translate="true">2 columns with left bar</label>
    </layout>
    <layout id="2columns-right">
        <label translate="true">2 columns with right bar</label>
    </layout>
    <layout id="3columns">
        <label translate="true">3 columns</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

You can find some useful information in below links.

[Magento theme structureenter link description here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html)

[Magento 2 front end architecture](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/frontend-theme-architecture/)

Comment: I agree on this point but I am asking how is design divided. As a frontend designer I should understand that how is it divided into like bootstrap has 12 column structure same goes with foundation framework. What exactly does magento follow?

Comment: Fine , designers have created own designs as per the layout structure, not taken from any framework.